# Should I use a repeater or a string builder to build dynamic html

Tags: asp.net

I think it's obvious that the framework wants use to keep the HTML in the aspx documents, and all code in the code behind to achieve a clean level of separation.

So what do we do when the `GridView` isn't good enough?

Should I:

- Use a `repeater` control to keep HTML in the presentation layer, but be forced to mix business logic in with the HTML
- Or should I mix HTML in with my code behind layer in the form of a `StringBuilder`?

Let's pretend that you said use the `Repeater` control.

Typically to return a product description I would do this:

`<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "desc") %>`

But then I run into the issue of when I want to only return 150 characters of the desc in case it's too long. If my datasource was LINQ to SQL I could just create a new string:

`string s = q.desc.lengh > 150 ? q.desc.SubString(0,150) + "..." : q.desc;`

How would I do the same inside the `repeater` within the aspx document if it is preferred I use the `repeater`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a Repeater, making html in code behind is messy and hard to maintain.

No reason why you can't use helper methods in the code behind (or elsewhere) to do this

```
<%# SomeMethod(Eval("desc")) %>
```

Or on the property of the class you are repeating, have an alternative version with a getter

```
public class SomeItem
{
    public string Desc { get; set; }

    public string DescSummary
    {
        get
        {
            return Desc.Length > 150 ? string.Format("{0}...", Desc.Substring(0, 150)) : Desc;
        }
    }
}
```

And in the repeater eval DescSummary

Comment: We use this method often.  Has a much better feel to it than the alternative

Comment: Looks like i'll be using the repeater with some helpers. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
<%# Eval("desc").ToString().Length > 150 ? Eval("desc").ToString().Substring(0, 150) : Eval("desc") %>
```